# Typescript: what is the purpose of a first "this" parameter?

Tags: typescript

I found the following method's signature

```
export function retry<T>(this: Observable<T>, count: number = -1): Observable<T> {
  return higherOrder(count)(this) as Observable<T>;
}
```

Where the first parameter is `this` and typed `Observable<T>`. While having `this` into the arguments seems to be wrong, the compiler accepts this syntax and I saw this pattern a few times already. Could someone explains what is its purpose?

Answer (score 3):

[From the docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#specifying-the-type-of-this-for-functions):

**Specifying the type of this for functions**
Following up on specifying the type of this in a class or an interface, functions and methods can now declare the type of this they expect.

By default the type of this inside a function is any. Starting with TypeScript 2.0, you can provide an explicit this parameter. this parameters are fake parameters that come first in the parameter list of a function:

```
function f(this: void) {
    // make sure `this` is unusable in this standalone function
}
```